# Extract the filename from the first argument

Tags: batch-file

How to extract just the filename (no extension) from %1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

echo %~n1

Answer (score 3):

If `%1` will contain just a filename (no path):

```
echo %~n1
```

If it could contain a path:

```
echo %~dpn1
```

will give you the absolute pathname.

**Beautiful isn't it!**  :-P  **[EDIT: These forms happily deal with quoted arguments, dequoting them in the process, as Johannes points out in a comment.]**

For more info: `help for`.  That's right, the relevant help is under the `FOR` command.  Which indicates that this syntax only works with `FOR` loop variables.  But actually it seems to work fine with `%1`, `%2`, etc.  Which might make you think that it would work with any environment variable -- but it doesn't.

I love `CMD.EXE`.

Comment: Why do you expect this to break on a quoted argument? The help explicitly states that all surrounding quotes will be removed.

Comment: You're right Johannes. The help says that `%~I` will "expand %I removing any surrounding quotes", leading me to the (incorrect) conclusion that using the other forms involving `~` would *not* remove surrounding quotes.

Comment: Thanks j_random. The first answer solved my problem, but you pointed some useful points (help for ?!, for example :)

Comment: all the single percent variables support the ~ syntax (command line arguments, for loop, call label)

Comment: Thanks Anders, cmd.exe appears saner by the minute! But what are call labels (in the context of "single percent variables")?

Comment: you can call a label, a subroutine basically. 

:echoandwait
echo %~1
pause
goto :EOF
...
call :echoandwait "hello world"